# PHP Image Upload linked to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I wrote a script to upload an image to a folder with PHP which should link the filename to MySQL.

I think after the long day I've missed something which I can't see :(

upload.php

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST">
 Photo: <input type="file" name="images"><br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Add"> 
 </form>
```

add.php

```
 <?php 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['images']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $images=($_FILES['images']); 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("formular") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES ('$images')") ; 

 //Writes the pictures to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

view.php

```
 <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("formular") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees") or die(mysql_error()); 
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //Outputs the image and other data
 Echo "<img src=images/".$info['images'] ."> <br>";
 }
 ?>
```

thx at all

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES ('$images')");
```

is probably not doing what you expect.  I believe you will see the word `Array` inserted into the table for each row.  You will need to insert each specific part of the array you want, like:

```
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES('{$images['name']}');
```

How many columns does the `employees` table contain?  If it has more than one, the query is likely failing with an invalid column count message.  Assign the result of that query to a variable and check it for errors (`$res = mysql_query(...); if (!$res) die(mysql_error());`

Start there, hope that helps.  Feel free to ask for further clarification or questions.

Comment: Thanks drew010 for your reply. It has only one column called images.

Comment: Ok in that case, browse the mysql table to see what it contains, I think you will just have a list of entries that all say `Array` due to trying to use an array as a string.  In PHP when you try to use an array as a string it just returns the word `Array` instead.

Comment: Try replacing `$images` with `$target` in your `INSERT INTO adressbuch` query. This line: `$images         = sanitize($_POST['images']);` does not do anything since the file is in the `$_FILES` array, not in `$_POST`.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Also change: `$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['images']['title']);` to `$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['images']['name']);`.  This line is also invalid: `$pic=($_FILES['images']['title']);` but `$pic` isn't used so that's fine.  See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for the array indexes you can use in `$_FILES`